# Node js, how to hide the secret key to the hosting managers

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have programed a node.js swing trading bot for the exchange Binance. It is a problem for me to run it 7 x 24 in my house, the energy or internet connection can fail. I think to upload it to a free hosting as Heroku. But I am questioning myself how to hide my Binance API secret key to the hosting managers.
Welcome any good idea!

Comment: You can use env variables that you can set directly in heroku.

Comment: I use dotenv but the keys are in text that can be read by the hosting administers. Thanks for you opinion

Comment: If you are afraid that heroku administrators are gonna do that, you can use a db connection and pull the credentials from there before using them.

Comment: There is no solution to a problem like this.  You HAVE to trust the physical security of your server and the credentials that it must store for its own use.  There is no way around that.  If you don't trust Heroku, then you need to find a hosting company you do trust.  There are ways to "obscure" keys so they aren't just lying around in the clear and might be less likely to be accidentally discovered, but that does not prevent a quality hacker that has physical access to your server from getting access to them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help 100% of your request, but i believe dotenv could help you.

[DotEnv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: I use .dotenv, but it is visible for the hosting administers, the keys are in ascii text.
Thanks for your opinion.